# How do i group product data with multiple of the same products per store

Tags: python, csv

I'm building a pyhon price tracker which allows me to enter some urls. The program then fetches their prices once each day and adds it to the csv file below.

I'm now looking for a way to show the price evolution of each product with a line chart but cannot find a way to get something like this below where i have prices from a product from a specific store.

```
Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite - coolblue = [123.00, 156.00, 186.00]
```

[image: csv dataset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `itertools.groupby` and some string handling like this

```
text = """Samsung Galaxy Tab So lite, 2022-10-17, coolblue, 501.99 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2022-10-17, coolblue, 589.00 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2022-10-17, bol, 596.99 
Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB, 2022-10-17, alternate, 129.90 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2022-10-17, alternate, 549.00 
Google Nest Mini, 2022-10-17, coolblue, 59.99 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite, 2022-10-18, coolblue, 501.99 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2822-10-18, coolblue, 589.0 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2022-10-18, bol, 596.99 
Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB, 2022-10-18, alternate, 129.9 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2022-10-18, alternate, 549.0 
Google Nest Mini, 2022-10-18, coolblue, 59.99 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite, 2022-18-19, coolblue, 501.99 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2822-10-19, coolblue, 589.0 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2022-10-19, bol, 596.99 
Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB, 2822-18-19, alternate, 129.9 
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE, 2022-10-19, alternate, 549.0 
Google Nest Mini, 2022-10-19, coolblue, 59.99
"""
from itertools import groupby
for k, v in groupby(sorted(text.splitlines(), key=lambda x: x.split(",")[0]), key=lambda x: (x.split(",")[0], x.split(",")[2])):
    print(k, [val.split(",")[-1] for val in v])
```

##### I have used google lens to extract text from image so it may be incorrect

##### Output

```
('Google Nest Mini', ' coolblue') [' 59.99 ', ' 59.99 ', ' 59.99']
('Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB', ' alternate') [' 129.90 ', ' 129.9 ', ' 129.9 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite', ' coolblue') [' 501.99 ', ' 501.99 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' coolblue') [' 589.00 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' bol') [' 596.99 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' alternate') [' 549.00 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' coolblue') [' 589.0 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' bol') [' 596.99 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' alternate') [' 549.0 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' coolblue') [' 589.0 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' bol') [' 596.99 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE', ' alternate') [' 549.0 ']
('Samsung Galaxy Tab So lite', ' coolblue') [' 501.99 ']
```

For File base

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("prices.csv") as f:
    text = f.read().splitlines()[1:]
        for k, v in groupby(sorted(text, key=lambda x: (x.split(",")[1], x.split(",")[3])), key=lambda x: (x.split(",")[1], x.split(",")[3])):
          print(k, [val.split(",")[-1] for val in v])
          print(" - ".join(list(k)), " = ", [val.split(",")[-1] for val in v]) # if you want the output like you have given in the question
```

Comment: Hi, you're onto something here, the first two are exacly how i want it! How would it work with csv files? I'm currently using pandas to work with it. 

I'll put some snippet below:

`Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite,2022-10-17,coolblue,501.99
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE,2022-10-17,coolblue,589.00
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE,2022-10-17,bol,596.99
Raspberry Pi 4 - 8 GB,2022-10-17,alternate,129.90
Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite,2022-10-18,coolblue,501.99
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE,2022-10-18,coolblue,589.0
Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE,2022-10-18,bol,596.99
Raspberry Pi 4 - 8 GB,2022-10-18,alternate,129.9`

Comment: Share your CSV file then i can show you else instead of text you can create `open('file.csv').read().splitlines()` but this will also include the header row

Comment: Here you go sir, "we.tl/t-Iqg3kMGP3r" couldn't paste the full wetransfer link i removed the https://

Comment: @ruben try with new code for file base

Comment: works perfectly for the products that only appear in 1 store, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you explain this? What you want and what you are getting in your question

Comment: Sorry for explaining it poorly.
What i'm getting: the same output as your output image.
What i'm looking for is to have the same output as the first three of your output.

The issue i think is that my file contains multiple items with the same name that appear in different stores. It happens with the 
```Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE```. I want to have one line (like the first three of your output) per store

Comment: Here's a screenshot of my output: https://imgur.com/a/dIZKXAK the colored ones should be grouped like the first 3 ones based on their store

Comment: @ruben I got your point now check my file based solution

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after a dictionary of store items with a list of prices. To achieve this you could do something along the lines of:

```
#Import a package to allow automatic creations of dictionaries containing lists
from collection import defaultdict

price_dictionary = defaultdict("list")

#Loop through lines, split on commas, append list items as values to product name keys
for line in data.csv:
    temp_list = []
    temp_list = line.split(",")
    price_dictionary[temp_list[0]].append(temp_list[3])
```

This isn't written as succinctly as possible but hopefully gives you an idea of you could do for your file.